# Tab icon filling tab when it shouldn't be?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a tabhost in an application that uses both a Tab Icon and Text for each tab. For the life of me, I cannot get the icon to be centered ABOVE the text instead of filling the entire tab. My searching has only resulted in others trying to get the icon to fill the entire tab. Every other example I have seen has the icon above the text.

Here is how I am setting up and adding the tabs:

```
tabs = (TabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.conference_tabhost);
tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
tabs.setup();

TabSpec tspecMenu = tabs.newTabSpec(tab_tag_menu);
tspecMenu.setIndicator("Menu", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_menu));
tspecMenu.setContent(R.id.tab_menu_view);
tabs.addTab(tspecMenu);
```

Here is the beginning of my layout:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/conference_tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TabWidget>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```